# how to convert (RTSP) rtp data from stream to jpg image

Tags: rtsp, rtp, gstreamer-1.0

```
/* send RTSP PLAY request */  
static void rtsp_play(CURL *curl, const char *uri, const char *range)
{
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
  printf("\nRTSP: PLAY %s\n", uri);
  my_curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, uri);
  my_curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, range);
  my_curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_PLAY);
  my_curl_easy_perform(curl);
  my_curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, NULL);
   /* fp=popen( "gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! openh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink rtsp://freja.hiof.no:1935/rtplive/definst/hessdalen03.stream","r" ); */   

  my_curl_easy_perform(curl);
  /* switch off using range again */
  my_curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question, not just in the body of the title

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps and create the gstreamer pipeline.

1. RTP data (NALU) received from the UDP socket need combined - to frame.
2. Encoded frame need to be decoded using the H.264 decoder.
3. Decoded RAW frame (YUV*/NV*) -> Jpeg Encoder - create a jpeg image.
4. Write this Jpeg image to .jpg file.